# Getting Duplicate Response in React-Apollo-client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have learning GraphQL from past few days ,Totally beginner  I tried to fetch some data using graphQL apollo react client . I use apollo server in both backend server and in client(React) . I tried to fetch the data but in response i get duplicate data as take example we have data of user with their department names and have role in it take role as Admin in intial so query i use to fetch is :

"db.users.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{department:"$department",role:"Admin",username:"$username"} } } ])"

i get perfect response in graphql (Server-side) by using :

```
{
  getUserswithrole{
    _id{
      username
      department
    }
  }
}
```

but when i tried in React-Apollo-client using useQuery Hooks. The result will look like:

```
getUserwithrole[
    { _id:{ username:"Samename" , role:"Admin" , department:"Samedepartment"} }
    { _id:{ username:"Samename" , role:"Admin" , department:"Samedepartment"} }
    { _id:{ username:"Samename" , role:"Admin" , department:"Samedepartment"} }
]
```

i tried the find the solution but didn't match with this problem .Solution i looked from source "internet" is GraphQL-deduplicator or GraphQL-crunch .please suggest me the what the possible solution i can try .

Thank you

Comment: not graphql problem, API should not allow to insert duplicated entries to DB

Comment: just fetching the data not inserting and username is different in all the documents/entries and when i fetch the result from graphql (serverside) give perfect result with different username with their departments

Comment: check response (network tab), show types definitions, result from graphiql/playground .... cached entries needs an id field to be normalized properly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840223/apollo-duplicates-first-result-to-every-node-in-array-of-edges